# Number of cliques in a graph and intersection number

Tags: graph-theory

Define the number of cliques in a graph $G$ to be $c(G)$ and the intersection number of the graph to be $\omega(G)$. I have been tasked to comment on the inequality between $c(G)$ and $\omega(G)$. I believe that $c(G)\geq \omega(G)$. Consider $S_v$ to be the set corresponding to the vertex $v$. Define $C_i=\{v \lvert i\in S_v\}$ for each $i\in S$. Now $C_i$ is a complete subgraph of $G$ and 
also if $C_i=C_j$ then we can remove $j$ and everything would remain same, thus getting intersection number less than $\omega(G)$ which is impossible.

I think the proof is correct, but I am a little unsure if I can indeed remove $j$, but to complete my task I must give an example where $c(G)>\omega(G)$, I can't seem to find it. Some help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite straightforward from the definition. You are comparing the number of cliques, with the minimum number of cliques that have a certain condition (that is, they cover the set of edges of the graph). In other words, you are comparing the size of a set, with the size of its subset.

It is known that the number of cliques in a graph is no smaller than the number of edges, i.e. $c(G) \geq m$. Also, we know that the number of edges is an upper bound for the intersection number, i.e. $\omega(G)\leq m$. Doesn't this imply the proof that you are looking for?